# How to cin a c++ string >= 1024 characters via bash shell?

Tags: c++, string, macos, bash, cin

On os X 10.8, I tried to redirect std input to c++ string via bash.

After I printed 1024th character, I even cannot press enter.

Could you please explain where the problem occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: Show us your C++ code, please. The problem is unlikely to be related to bash. And what exactly happens when you press enter?

Comment: @KeithThompson: It does surely look like an issue with bash not allowing lines longer than 1024 characters in his configuration...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Bash shouldn't be affecting the execution of his C++ program. Actually, we need to see both the C++ program (or a smaller working version of it) *and* the exact bash command used to invoke it.

Comment: When I copy and paste from that PDF, I get [uncompilable, barely-readable garbage](http://pastebin.com/rM13FufE). Can you please paste it in text format, or at least a copy-able PDF?

Comment: Even better, can you provide a much smaller and simpler example that demonstrates the whole thing? For example, if your whole program is just `string s; getline(cin, s);` does it have the same problem?

Comment: PS, was this code written by your professor, or by you? If this is code by a novice taking an intro to C++, it's pretty good, but if it's written by someone who's _teaching_ such a class, you might want to find a new professor…

Comment: When I visit the link in your previous comment, I get "This folder is empty". In this case it may not matter much, but in general this is why it's best to include code directly in your question, so it will remain visible to future readers.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The OP apparently removed the PDF from his dropbox as soon as he got an answer to the question. Which is normally a very bad thing to do, as it makes the question useless to anyone who comes along later—but, since the C++ code turned out to be irrelevant, and the PDF wasn't useful to get the C++ code even if it were relevant, I think it's OK in this case.

Comment: I don't think this question was closed appropriately. The tty line limit is a real, and pretty general, problem that many people run into. Maybe it needs to be rewritten to make it clear that `cin` and `bash shell` and even "Mac" aren't the key issues here—it's just reading from a tty on any Unix. But, unless there's a dup (I tried a few searches and didn't turn anything up… but then I'm guessing many people asking this question wouldn't know what they were asking), I think it's a useful question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `bash`, or with the C++ code. To verify this, this trivial program has the same problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int, char**) {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

And so does this Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
raw_input()
```

And you can try running under different shells and see that it makes no difference.

The problem is that a TTY in line mode always has a max line length, and this one happens to have a max line length of 1024.

So, this isn't even really a programming question; it's a TTY question. Which is why you can find a dup over at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/264407/macosx-10-6-7-cuts-off-stdin-at-1024-chars) instead of here. See the discussions there on the various ways to deal with this.

However, if you want to deal with it from within your program, rather than globally, you can check whether `stdin` is a `tty`, and if so use `termios` functions to temporarily turn off line mode. For example, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int, char**) {
  struct termios told;

  if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &told);
    struct termios tnew = told;
    tnew.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &tnew);
  }

  std::string s;
  std::getline(std::cin, s);

  if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &told);
  }
}
```

However, you'll obviously want real error handling, and you'll probably want to use RIAA to stash and restore the original termios settings, and you should probably read `man termios` to understand what you're doing and what other effects it will have (and whether you want to do anything else).